# Create plist through command line

Tags: applications, plist

Forgive me if there is a better way todo this, but I have an app that is generated without a plist, this is partly due to the build system that is cross platform. Is there a way to generate a plist from the command line? I looked at `defaults` but I can't seem to generate one. I need to be able to set one key `CFBundleExecutable`.

Thanks.

Comment: Plist files are simple xml or text (or binary representations of them). Please check [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27379507/creating-and-writing-into-plist-with-terminal-or-bah-script)

Comment: Why can't you have plist file on other platforms? It doesn't have to be in binary format.

Comment: @klanomath Yep I will do that if there is a less error prone method.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek I guess there is nothing wrong with having a plist on every platform but that could lead to confusion with developers on Windows/Linux.

Comment: What do you means by "I looked at `defaults` but I can't seem to generate one."?  I have no problem creating a `.plist` file using `defaults`.  Did you read then man page for it?

Comment: @user3439894 Yes I did, I must have missunderstood something. I tried `defaults write ...` but it produces nothing, not even an error.

Comment: @user3439894 I think I messed up on the path for that. If you push that as answer I'll select it.

Comment: If you want the `.plist` file in a specific location use the fully qualified pathname.  Don't use `~/..` as it might still end up in `~/Library/Preferences`.  The man page example `defaults write  ̃/Desktop/TestFile foo bar` doesn't end up on the Desktop as it says it will (under 10.8.5 anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example creates a `com.domain.programname.plist` file in:

`~\Library\Preferences`

```
defaults write com.domain.programname CFBundleExecutable $value
```

If you want an `Info.plist` file this example creates one on your Desktop:

```
defaults write /Users/$USER/Desktop/Info CFBundleExecutable ExecutableName
```

You could set the path to inside the `.app` bundle, say it's in Applications:

```
defaults write /Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Info CFBundleExecutable ExecutableName
```

For other permutations read: `man defaults`

[image: Info.plist file]